# Regex to replace multiple characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a word counter function but it doesn't account for people using poor punctuation, for example:

> "hello.world"

That would only count is as 1 word. Instead it should count that as 2 words. Which is why I am using this RegEx;

```
negWords.replace(/[,.!?;\s]+/g,' ');
```

That works fine but if people use double space or punctuation it counts that as a word also;

> ' hello,,' Is counted as 2 words,

but it doesn't count more occurrences as more than 1 word.

> ' hello,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, ' is still counted as 2 words.

Edited for more context.

Comment: I don't get what you want. Can you be clearer ? And please don't speak of count words if you're trying to fix the replace.

Comment: See my updated question, hopefully that will make it clearer.

Answer (score 5):

To get the words from your text, you can do

```
var words = text.split(/\W+/).filter(Boolean);
```

and the count is `words.length`.

Here the `filter(Boolean)` call removes empty strings from the array.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` symbol means that it should accept one or more of each of the characters in the group. If you want only one, then you need to remove the `+`.

```
negWords.replace(/[,.!?;\s]/g,' ');
```

If you want to catch one punctuation character or space followed any amount of whitespace, try this:

```
negWords.replace(/[,.!?;\s]\s*/g,' ');
```

Comment: If you're just trying to count words, then @dystroy 's version is better.